Why i can found “Cancel” & How make Cancel then click Icon show GUI only one click?
So i want make Click Icon Show another UI with UI Cancel but if i click Cancel instead Icon, i need to click Icon Double time.
enter image description here
local ACHIEVEMENTS = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.GUI1
local Cancel = script.Can
local open = true
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if open == true then
        open = false
        ACHIEVEMENTS:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.32, 0,0.134, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
        task.wait(0.5)
        ACHIEVEMENTS.Visible = true
    else
        open = true
        ACHIEVEMENTS:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.32, 0,1, 0), "InOut", "Quad", 0.5, true)
        ACHIEVEMENTS.Visible = true
    end
end)

I want make LocalScript "Cancel" use then LocalScript "AnotherGUI" Just Click only click one and will Show GUI

Describe exactly what you are trying to achieve. I'm a bit confused by the wording of the post and what the script is trying to do.
